# Downsize image when training yolov5 model

Tags: python, yolo, yolov5

I am looking into making my custom YoloV5 model faster, based on my current results where I have trained a on ~20k (1280 × 960) images with a configuration based on yolov5l6.yaml (A P6 model I assume)

This gives me a very well performing model, and I would now like to explore smaller/simpler models.

Option A: Is the simple and try to train with a medium/small/nano version of the P6 model

Option B: I would like to try going to an image size of 640 by using a P5 model.

**My question is:** do I need to manually resize my images to 640x640 to efficiently train a P5 model (e.g. based on yolov5m.yaml), or can I simply pass the desired image size as a parameter to train.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imgsz flag determines the size of the images fed to the model, this is also true for training. So you can simply do the following

```
python train.py ... --imgsz 640  # training on 640 images
```

To check that this is actually the case you can

```
print(img.shape)
```

just before the image batch is fed to the model

[Reference](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/cdd804d39ff84b413bde36a84006f51769b6043b/train.py#L442)

Comment: So to be sure: Will the train.py script actually resize the 1280x960 images to 640x480 before/while doing the training?

Comment: Updated comment